# TDLib (Telegram Database library) authentication and login example by Bannerets/tdl (Node.js pakage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, tdlib

I so search about `TDLib (Telegram Database library) authentication and login example` but can't found any things :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created it

Now you can found example hear:

[Github: TDLib node.js authentication and login example)](https://github.com/mortezaataiy/nodejs-tdlib-login-example)